# Unable to add or edit products in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have a website in Magento 1.9.2. It has nearly 6,000 products. I am trying to update or delete products but I am unable to do so as I am getting a strange error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'harbourlivingcom_1.premier_prod_priceupdate' doesn't exist, query was: insert into premier_prod_priceupdate (sku,newprice, oldprice, datetime) values('AADZWS','27.99','17.9900',Now())
```

I have no table in my database and have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a table that doesn't exists in your database , `harbourlivingcom_1.premier_prod_priceupdate`

If you recently have installed any module, looks like the sql script of this module is not get executed.

I suggest for you to get Magerun tool 
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

and run the following command

`n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run`

to run all setup scripts in your Magento.

Otherwise, you should check any observer on this custom module, that fired every time you update / delete product .

Comment: I have disable all custom module and it get fixed. But how can I figure out which custom module I need to disable.  Right Now I disable all custom module and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

I think this is from some custom module which is trying to save some data in premier_prod_priceupdate table whenever you will update or delete any product.
 In your whole project you can search for premier_prod_priceupdate table name and check the custom module.